# Content negotiation for spray in error handlers

Tags: scala, spray, spray-routing

I am trying to use content negotiation in a spray-based application. The following test describes my expected behaviour. Unfortunately, this is not what I see (Put to github for size):

https://gist.github.com/Norwae/49c26613f91c32482bb1

Essentially, content-negotiation seems to work fine when complete() is invoked from within the normal routing. It does not seem to function at all within an `ExceptionHandler`, where the first available serializer is selected regardless of `Accept` header.

Is there any way to achieve the same behaviour in the exception handler? Are there any alternatives other than using `onComplete` and handling errors explicitly all over the place?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?